# Blazor WASM Core Hosted .Net 7 configure Identity

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM Core Hosted .Net 7 application.  When I set it up, I selected to add Individual Accounts.  I want to Authenticate to an external identity provider (not use User Name and Passwords).  I will authenticate with the external provider using OIDC, get back the user's claims (assuming they authenticate) and manage the users roles/claims in the application.  I don't want to allow users to register for accounts or require users to confirm their accounts.  This is an internal application where admins will create accounts for users.  Right now, what I have setup will authenticate with the external identity provider but when the user authenticates for the first time, they will be forced to register their email (which I dont want them to do).  If they are not already in the system, they should just be redirected to the app to handle this with an empty set of claims.  In addition, I just want an authentication process that is single page.  Right now, the app has a  control that has a login button.  That button redirects the user to a new login page, which then requires the user to click another button to login.

Here is what I have in my code:

**MyApp.Server Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, UserClaimsTransformation>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();    

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-blazor";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OpenIDConnect:ClientId").Get<string>();
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OpenIDConnect:ClientSecret").Get<string>();
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OpenIDConnect:Authority").Get<string>();
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.UsePkce = true;
        
        //events
     
    }).AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

**MyApp.Server UserClaimsTransformation.cs:**

```
public class UserClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public UserClaimsTransformation(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal>TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var clone = principal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;
            var identity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.IsAuthenticated);
            var loggedInUserId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "emailaddress")?.Value;    
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loggedInUserId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);    
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                var claim = new Claim(newIdentity.RoleClaimType, role);
                newIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
            }    
            foreach (var claim in userClaims)
            {
                newIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
            }    
            return clone;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to create a custom authentication class that implements AuthenticationStateProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider {
    // Entry Point
    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() {
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(await Get_User_Identity())));
    }

...

}
```

The class requires one override method: GetAuthenticationStateAsync()

Then register the class to override AuthenticationStateProvider:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider
            , CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

Now when your app starts you will gain authentication control in your custom class. Hook into your intranet auth service and then return AuthenticationState to the app.
I build apps in a similar walled garden with SSO authentication and I want to know who is using the app but not have them log in. Works great.

Note that as with other objects in Blazor, if you are using pre-rendering, the code will fire twice at startup. There are a few ways to deal with this. Either turn off pre-render or only do something if the app is not in pre-render:

```
if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Response.HasStarted == true) { }
```

The context accessor is registered like:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and then injected into the class:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
```

Via the constructor:

```
public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor){
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```